# Why is the same chapter repeating in my thesis?

Tags: chapters, thesis

I have stored all the chapters of my thesis along with the thesis source file in a single folder. There are $9$ chapters in total. The source code is shown below.

```
\begin{document}
\large
\pagenumbering{roman}
\include{frontpage}
\include{Acknowledgments}
\include{Preface}
\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{notation}
\include{Introduction}
\include{Basic}
\include {chapter-3}
\include {chapter-4}
\include {Chapter-5}
\include {Chapter-6}
\include {chapter-8}
\include {Conclusion}
\include {bibliography}
\end{document}
```

Chapter no. 7 is repeating twice when I include {chapter-7} in the source. Moreover, chapter no. 7 is shown in the thesis pdf even without being included in the source file. Where is the wrong, I couldn't diagnose?

Comment: Sorry for an unclear question. I had no idea as how to put latex commands in this page?

Comment: This is just a wild guess.  Have you looked at chapters 6 and 8 to make sure they don't contain either the content of chapter 7, or a line `\input{hapter-7}`?  (Using `\include` within an `\include`d file would produce an error.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton fixed. Actually chapter-7 was contained in chapter-6.

Comment: It's always good to check the easy thing first.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a duplication of content was caused by repetition of that content in two files, as acknowledged in a comment.